# How can I disable a program from asking for sudo privileges?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, sudo, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17.1-mate. For some weird reason the `ping` command asks me for `sudo` privileges in order to run. I have a Python script that uses `ping` in order to see if my AP is up and running, but I want to run this script with regular user privileges.

I know that you can edit the `visudo` file, but that only makes it not ask for a password; I want it not to ask for `sudo` at all. Is there any way to achieve that?

This is the piece of code I use to ping the AP:

```
p = Popen(shlex.split('ping -c 1 %s' % self._ap_host), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.communicate()
res = p.returncode
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem when doing a manual ping in a terminal? Do you have selinux installed? Then check this out: http://www.engardelinux.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=225 as SELinux can (which is a good thing, actually) require proper authorization for that.

If not, i'd check the firewall (sudo iptables -L) which can e.g. deny ICMP to certain users, too.

Comment: thanks, the problem has been solved. the IPtables issue was checked and not the problem. and yes it did happen in manual ping through terminal also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was solved!

a friend gave me the answer.

in order to make all users run the ping command as root simply make sure that the command /bin/ping is under root ownership. then run 
`sudo chmod +s /bin/ping`.

and voila! :)